# Is the "shortcut" for evaluating "A && B" part of one of the ISO standards?

Tags: c

If `A` is false, then `A && B` is false, so there is no need to check `B`. So very often, the compiler writes assembly in such a way that if `A && B` is to be evaluated and `A` is evaluated as false, then `B` is not evaluated.

Can I assume that that all compilers which adhere to ISO standard (let's say C99 or more modern), will behave like this?

The reason I ask is that in my program, I have the statement `if (i > -1 && x[i] > 3)`. So if `i` is negative but `x[i] > 3` still gets evaluated, this will lead to a segmentation fault.

Comment: yes its guranteed

Comment: Yes, you can definitely rely on this behavior (Boolean short-circuiting) though I don't have a reference handy.

Comment: Yes, but careful not to also assume that other operators (like `+` or `-` for example) will evaluate left-to-right serially.

Comment: Try to create a nested if-else statement in which x[i] > 3 will only be evaluated inside of i <= -1 block.

Comment: @IvanSilkin Yes, I was just hoping to avoid this so the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the ISO C standard does guarantee short-circuit evaluation for the `&&` operator.

[§6.5.13 ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13p4) states the following:

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.